# Is it possible to use Microsoft Dynamics CRM Data Migration Manager with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-dynamics-crm

Ok. Here is my set up: I have a a windows server 2008 with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 installed.

On a separate windows server machine is the database with SQL Server 2008 installed. We managed to get this working fine.

However, I can't get the MSCRM Migration manager to work. I have tried to run the utility on the CRM server, the SQL server and on my local machine. In all cases it will fail when verifying the SQL server with "Failed to determine the SQL data root path for CRM instance." In the verification screen it says it's checking "Microsoft SQL Server 2005,"  which of course, we don't have. We have 2008.

Does this mean the migration manager does not work with 2008? This seems kind of silly to me. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, I got this response from an expert on CRM.

> Install the SQL Express on the
>   workstation and run DDM on the
>   Workstation. It doesn’t need to get to
>   the SQL 2008 server.

That worked. I thought I would leave this question in case anyone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

same problems! Do you use the Express SQL 2005 on the Workstation (client maschine)?. Or the SQL 2008 Express Version?

Comment: I actually don't know. The CRM install will install Express for you. I should be the correct version automatically.